# Dynamically adding CheckBoxes - Runtime error 424

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Hi i've copy/pasted the code from a TheEngineer-answer - I have slightly modified the code, so it collects data from an array instead of a worksheet. I keep getting `RuneTime Error 424`, and when I read MS help on `Error 424` it says I should enable `Microsoft DAO 3.5 Object Library` my Excel only have `3.6`. I guess newer version? But I am still getting an error. Can someone help me??

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim LastColumn  As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

    Call test ' Here i run array code (The array is filled with data)

    TestArr = UniqueProvisionArray
    LastColumn = UBound(TestArr)

    For i = 0 To LastColumn
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
        chkBox.Caption = TestArr(i).Value
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because of the line `chkBox.Caption = TestArr(i).Value`. That is an incorrect way to retrieve data from an array.

Here is a sample code to make it work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim LastColumn  As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim TestArr(1)

    TestArr(0) = 1
    TestArr(1) = 2

    LastColumn = UBound(TestArr)

    For i = 0 To LastColumn
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
        chkBox.Caption = TestArr(i)
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
    Next i
End Sub
```

One other thing...

You may want to change `chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)` to `chkBox.Top = 5 + (i * 20)` else your first Checkbox will not be visible ;)

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This is why i love AND hate VBA - One stupid .value messes everthing up, but when it is fixed it its like an orgasm :-D

Comment: Now that's a compliment!